# Change language of error messages in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 to write a bunch of queries.  I have installed French versions of Windows XP and SQL Server thus all SQL error messages appear in French.  I would prefer to see the error messages in English.  Any idea how to change the language of the error messages?  I won't  reinstall the machine.

Patrick

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution 1 minute later :

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH
```

Comment: This sets complete language - include first day in week (Sunday instead of Monday) and date format (mdy instead of dmy)...

Comment: You can set first day of week with `SET DATEFIRST 1` to monday and dateformat with `SET DATEFORMAT DMY` after you set the language. With `DBCC USEROPTIONS` you can see which options are active right now.

Answer (score 6):

You must pay attention to case, depending your server configuration. In "case sensitive" servers:

```
SET LANGUAGE English
```

Comment: Accepted answer didn't work for me with `ENGLISH` in uppercase but `English` did work. Thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, in the SSMS international settings was English, but the error messages after queries were in the same language as the environment language.

`SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH` command didn't work for me. I have SSMS 2018 version. After some research, I found the solution.

In the initial connection to the server in the "Connect to Server" tab, choose Options -> Additional Connection Parameters.

In there input this:

`Language=English`

And connect to the server, query error messages started to be in the English language.

Comment: This method worked for me.